# Python - Property Getter as a lambda with a parameter

Tags: python, lambda

Being new to python I just came across the `property` keyword which basically lets you assign getters and setters. I came up with this simple example

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,var=2):
        self.var= var

    def setValue(self,var):
        print("Setting value called")
        self._var  = var

    def getValue(self):
        print("getting value")

    var = property(getValue,setValue)
```

Now in my django project I came across with something like this (using a lambda in a property)

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    likes_cheese = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    puppy_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

User.profile = property(lambda u : UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

I had no clue that you could use a lambda inside a property. Now from what I understand is that it is setting the getter of the `profile` as a lambda and the getter requires a parameter. This kind of confused me. So I decided to try my own example

```
class double:
    def setValue(self,var):
        print("Setting value called")
        self._var  = var

    def getValue(self):
        print("getting value")

    #var = property(getValue,setValue)
    var = property(lambda x: print("The value of parameter is" + str(x)))

d =double()
d.var #Call the getter but how do i pass a value parameter to it ?
```

Now in my case how can i pass a parameter to the lambda ?

Comment: The value of the first parameter is `self`..

Comment: Can you explain that please.  I am still a bit confused

Comment: I've added the explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal/idomatic way to write a property is:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 42

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, val):
        self._foo = val
```

as you can see, like all other method definitions in Python, the first parameter to the method is `self`.

You can name the parameter whatever you want (don't!), but the first parameter will always be the object itself.

The nice syntax above can be deconstructed to

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 42

    def foo_get(self):
        return self._foo

    def foo_set(self, val):
        self._foo = val

    foo = property(foo_get, foo_set)
```

and instead of passing function *names* to `property` we can instead use lambdas:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 42

    def foo_set(self, val):
        self._foo = val

    foo = property(lambda self: self._foo, foo_set)
```

we can't pass the setter as a lambda since lambdas cannot contain assignments.  Here I've continued using `self` as the parameter name, but I could use any variable name, e.g.:

```
foo = property(lambda u: u._foo, foo_set)
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me out of this misery with this awesome explanation.

Comment: We actually can use lambda as a setter, we can make it work without assignment. :)

Comment: It shouldn't be a goal in itself to use lambdas here. The Django example creates the property outside the class (i.e. after the class has been defined), and using a lambda in that case prevents polluting the module namespace.  People are most used to seeing properties written like in my first example though, so I would suggest following the herd (unless you have weighty reasons not to... ;-)

Comment: Of course it shouldn't! And I'd strongly discourage the use of `property()` function like that, because decorating is much more clear and expressful. I just meant you can actually do that, not that it's a good practice or something.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like this.

```
class double:
    def __init__(self):
        self._var = None

    var = property(lambda self: self._var,
                   lambda self, value: setattr(self, "_var", value))

d = double()
d.var = 3
print(d.var)
```

When you work with bound methods, the first parameter passed to them is always an instance of a class. It's named `self` in vast majority of the cases. But it's only a convention, you can name it whatever you want, so when you do just

```
var = property(lambda x: print("The value of parameter is" + str(x)))
```

`x` points to the instance, and `str(x)` is something like `<__main__.double object at 0x105f47a90>`, which is clearly not what you want.

Second, a getter doesn't accept any other arguments, because... well, you really don't need anything else but instance.

Third, we can also use a lambda as a setter; we need 2 parameters here, instance and value, but lambda cannot contain an assignment, so we gotta workaround it with `setattr()` function.

But if this approach used not just to train and explore, I'd recommend to fallback to `@property` syntax as shown by @thebjorn.